# Compute distances from a vector to a matrix of vectors

Tags: tensor, distance-measure

Let $\vec{a} \in \mathbb{R}^\alpha$, and let $H$ be a rank 3 tensor with dimensions $M_{[i \in \mathbb{N}]} \times N_{[j \in \mathbb{N}]} \times \alpha_{[k \in \mathbb{N}]}$ (where the subscript are the indexing of each one of the dimensions).

We can analogously look at the tensor $H$ as a matrix $H'$ which each element is an $\mathbb{R}^\alpha$ vector.

I wish to compute a norm (lets say for sake of example the $\| \cdot \|_2^2$ norm, squared here just to avoid taking the root after the computation of differences) of vector $\vec{a}$ with each element of matrix $H'$

A simple algorithm (using python without numpy as example) for that can be expressed as:

```
D = [[0 for i in range(M)] for j in range(N)]
for i in range(M):
    for j in range(N):
        norm = 0
        for k in range(alpha):
            norm += (a[k] - H[i][j][k])**2
        D[i][j] == norm
```

Mathematically we could write:

$D_{i,j} = \| H_{i,j} - \vec{a} \|_2^2 = \sum_{k=1}^\alpha \left(H_{{i,j}_k} - a_k \right)^2$

My question are:

1. There is any mathematical operation that express this more clearly? Any  matrix/tensor operation that can express that more concisely?
2. Is there better algorithms, approaches to this computation? Since I will run large tensors with large vectors I will calculate the distance to many input vectores. My idea is to optimize using gpus, probably with tensorflow.

Comment: Is it important that your vectors are arrange over two indices $i,j$? Couldn't you just unroll these indices into one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is going to be an IO-bound operation, so there is little practical advantage in looking for alternative formulations. There are two things you can do to speed that up:

1. choose the order of indices and for loops to make sure that memory accesses are as contiguous as possible. In your case (assuming Fortran-style memory layout, which should be what Python does, and assuming `a` takes less space than `D`), I think you want to reshape `H` so that `k` is the first index, and then you want to swap the order of the `i` and `j` loops.
2. compile that loop. It doesn't matter much what language you use, Cython, Numba, Tensorflow (using a GPU may matter, of course, under the right conditions), C, Julia, whatever. Just not plain-old interpreted, weakly-typed Python.

As an alternative to doing 2 by hand, look if you can find a library function that does it for you. For instance, a quick Google search returned [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist), but I don't know if it is compiled and fast enough for your purposes.

Matlab users would tell you to use `bsxfun` or a subtraction with singleton expansion `reshape(a, [1,1,length(a)]) - H` followed by [`vecnorm`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vecnorm.html), which probably is the fastest thing you can do in Matlab, but is still not optimal because it loops through $H$ twice.